# resultant map to be separated on the basis of comma in java

Tags: java, java-8

I have developed this below program which sorts the `HashMap` on the basis of the keys as shown below:

```
Map<String, String> countryCapitalMap = new HashMap<>();
countryCapitalMap.put("guyana", "georgetown");
countryCapitalMap.put("nepal", "kathmandu");
countryCapitalMap.put("australia", "canberra");
countryCapitalMap.put("india", "newdelhi");
countryCapitalMap.put("japan", "tokyo");
System.out.println("Original Map : \n" + countryCapitalMap);

Map<String, String> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Stream<Map.Entry<String, String>> stream = countryCapitalMap.entrySet().stream();
stream.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey()).forEach(System.out::print);
```

Now the program is working fine and its output is:

```
Original Map: 
{guyana=georgetown, japan=tokyo, nepal=kathmandu, australia=canberra, india=newdelhi}
australia=canberraguyana=georgetownindia=newdelhijapan=tokyonepal=kathmandu
```

As shown in the case of the original map that it is comma separated, so I want the resultant map that is sorted on the basis of the keys to be also comma separated. Please advise how to achieve that.

Looking for a solution with method references only.

Comment: Why do you declare a variable `sortedMap` and initialize it with a new `LinkedHashMap`, when you never use it?

Answer (score 3):

```
forEach(x -> System.out.println(x + ", "));
```

*or*

```
String result = stream.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
         .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: Compact, but has the disadvantage that the last element also has a trailing `, ` (the first solution).

Comment: You can however remove it with `result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you output only the text of the entries. So you only use `Entry#toString` which prints `key=value`. The map itself concatenates all those entry-texts with commas.

You can fix this by building the `String` on your own, for example by using `StringBuilder`, `StringJoiner`, `String#join` or `Collectors#joining`:

```
String result = stream
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())    // Sorted
    .map(Map.Entry::toString);             // Entry -> String
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));    // Collect by joining

// Print the result
System.out.println(result);
```

---

Another solution using `StringJoiner`:

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", ");
stream.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())  // Sorted
    .map(Map.Entry::toString);             // Entry -> String
    .forEach(sj::add);                     // Add to joiner

// Print the result
String result = sj.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

---

Here are the documentations of said classes:

- [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)
- [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)
- [String#join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-)
- [Collectors#joining](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-)